# .NET portable application stops working on windows terminal server until stopped for every user

Tags: c#, .net, rdp, terminal-server

We deploy our .NET applications (.NET-Framework 4.5.2 and upwards) on a network drive. To explain, we build it in Visual Studio and copy the contents of bin/release. Several users who are connected to different terminal servers of Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2016 or Windows Server 2019 via RDP run the application. Most of the time it works great, but from time to time the application stops working. Either it doesn't start at all or it crashes at a specific action. The action at which it crashes is always different. After we close the application for all users on the terminal server, it works again without any problems. It looks like all users share the same process and if one crashes, it crashes for everyone.

Is this a known problem and do you have any solutions? For easy and fast update reasons, we cannot install the application directly on the server.

Comment: I've never deployed a single executable for multiple users to run at once. It sounds messy. Why are you doing it that way rather than as an online only Click Once application?

Comment: does that copy the whole application to the users profile? that would be a problem for our disk size.

Comment: It copies the whole application. If disk space for a custom compiled app is a problem then you either have an undersized terminal server, or a very large application. One suggestion I just read is to not deploy the binaries to a network share, but to install it on the terminal server like a normal app. That allows the server to treat it as an application like any other, and avoid certain file system behaviors that can cause conflicts between multiple users.